# How to run two python functions at same time?

Tags: python, database, multithreading, parallel-processing

**Background**

I have a python script that compares the same table across two different environments for e.g. production and development. Now the thing is to compare the data, I need to fetch data from both environments at the same time. I am using the Oracle database here.

**My strategy until now:**

My main python script launches two different python scripts at the same time using os.startfile(). Each script fetches data from their respective environment for e.g. fetch_prod.py fetches data from production and then save data into an excel file as prod_data.xlsx.

My main script checks every one minute to see if both excel files are present. After which It reads excel into a pandas data frame and does its comparison.

**What I want**

I need to run both data fetching functions parallelly inside my main script and need to wait until they signal that have fetched all the data.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code!

Comment: Since most of the delay is network / db related, I'd probably go for asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the python [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

You can run something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def read_db1(some_arg):
    pass
    # Do Something

def read_db2(some_arg):
    pass
    # Do Something

def main():
    db1_proc = Process(target=read_db1, args=('bla',))
    db1_proc.start()

    db2_proc = Process(target=read_db2, args=('bla',))
    db2_proc.start()

    db1_proc.join()
    db2_proc.join()

    # Do something now that both processes are done
```